# remove html with jquery before carousel plugin runs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to remove html from an unordered list based on missing images, this is what I'm using

```
$("img").error(function () {
    $(this).parent().remove(); 
});
```

which strips out the list entry fine. The problem is that the images are used in a carousel, controlled by http://www.thomaslanciaux.pro/jquery/jquery_carousel.htm and they are counted before they are removed which results in blank frames.

any suggestions in getting this code to run in a way which removes the html before the carousel processes it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another listener on load `$('img').load(...)` that keeps track of all images, and once all images have been loaded or error'd out, you load the carousel plugin.

For example:

```
var startCarousel, imgCount = $('img').length;

startCarousel = function() {
    if (imgCount === 0) {
        $('img').carousel(); // TODO adjust this to match the way you start your carousel
    }
}  

$('img').load(function() {
    imgCount--;
    startCarousel();
})
.error(function() {
    imgCount--;
    $(this).parent().remove();
    startCarousel();
});
```

Comment: hi, sorry, something odd seems to be happening with ie, it doesn't load properly when I go to a page but it will after a page refresh or two... not sure what's happening

Comment: It may depend on when you are executing the script. If images are already loaded when you add the .load() listener, it will never be triggered. Maybe you should check the image sizes or something to determine if they've been loaded already and if so decrement the imgCount.